# Document.cookie does not seem to set the cookie

Tags: javascript, forms, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie when a user clicks on a button (as a simple web form). The code I am trying to use looks like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.cookie = 'q=1';" value="Add to Cart" />
```

It seems simple enough, but every debugger I'm using says there are no cookies being set, and when I try to access the cookie later it doesn't work. This is giving me innumerable headaches and I'd appreciate help.

Thanks.

Comment: [Check this on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie).

Comment: Did the answer help at all? I added a link on how to enable cookies on different browsers.

Comment: Give us a fiddle so we can check exactly what you are doing wrong[setting the cookie or picking it up] ?

Comment: user: your answer was definitely helpful, although I wish I could figure out why the cookie isn't working for chrome.                 Arun: http://jsfiddle.net/nrmX4/1/

Answer (score 1):

Strange because it works for me....

```
<input id="mybtn" type="button" onclick="document.cookie = 'q=1';" value="Add to Cart" />
```

So that would indicate to me that somewhere in your internet options you have security set to not accept cookies from certain sources I'd say. Try relaxing your security settings and see how you go (try in a different browser even).

[Click here for instructions to enable cookies](http://www.wikihow.com/Enable-Cookies-in-Your-Internet-Web-Browser)

Here is a jsfiddle where it's working for me (you will have to use firefox/chrome because IE doesn't like it)

ALSO the issue about not being able to access the cookie later could be for multiple reasons depending on HOW you are trying to access it. Of course if it doesn't exist then you can't access it but I'd say you would start a whole new quest for accessing the cookie (after you read some doco and try some things)

Comment: First off, thanks for the advice to try it on different browsers. Despite the fact that I have cookies enabled for Chrome, it just doesn't want to accept one from my site. Things got really weird when I set up a jsfiddle: now firefox and chrome recognize the cookie, as you said, but IE does not.  Here's the link to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nrmX4/1/

Comment: @sa What happens if you have a page on your site which does not have any other javascript or anything (just a blank page) with those buttons from your jsfiddle? (just trying to see if anything else in the page is conflicting with it)

Comment: @user1567453, both links are the same.